# Firebase: Access a snapshots children using swift3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the value of multiple children of my snapshot in order to append my cellDataArray by name and speed. 
My code is working for name, but not for speed..

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("BasicInfo")
    let query = ref?.queryOrdered(byChild: "Operator")
    query?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                let name = child.key
                let speed = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "Speed")
                self.cellDataArray.append(cellData(mainText: name, Speed: ""))
                self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
```

This is my Firebase structure:
[image]

Comment: Not related but you need to reload the `tableView` after the `for loop` on main thread. Can you please show your Firebase structure.

Comment: Ok, its there! Tank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to access the `value` property of `FIRDataSnapshot` to get the `Speed`.

```
for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
    let name = child.key
    if let dic = child.value as? [String:Any], let speed = dic["Speed"] as? Int
       let operator = dic["Operator"] as? String {  
          print(operator)
          self.cellDataArray.append(cellData(mainText: name, Speed: "\(speed)"))
    }
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: No, not really.. It seems that the value of all children of Bob is added as one single value for each key. But I cannot verify 'cause I don't get any log when print(dic). Do you have an idea how this could come? Thank you so much!!:)

Comment: @user3138007 Can you please check what is output of simply `child.value`?

Comment: For child.value I get:                    
Optional({
            "Speed" = 30;
            Operator = "World Marine Offshore";
        })                    This is weird cause speed is a ""

Comment: @user3138007 Then above solution will work, or your speed is in string format?

Comment: Yeh it is, how comes that speed is in String format, but operator not?

Comment: @user3138007 Don't get your above comment, you want value of `operator` field also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134454/discussion-between-user3138007-and-nirav-d).

Comment: @user3138007 Check the edited answer to get value of operator.